# raise ValueError("name for name_scope must be a string."

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have defined doubled conv layers in Keras, to use it as a reference in the Unet architecture, like this:

```
class ConvBlock(keras.Model):
  def __init__(self,in_channels):
    super(ConvBlock,self).__init__()
    self.in_channels = in_channels
    self.conv = keras.Sequential(
        layers.Conv2D(filters=self.in_channels,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding="same",use_bias=False),
#       layers.BatchNormalization(),
#       layers.ReLU(),       
        layers.Conv2D(filters=self.in_channels,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding="same", use_bias=False),
#       layers.BatchNormalization()
#       layers.ReLU(),
    )

  def call(self,input_tensor):
    return self.conv(input_tensor)
```

During the unit test, i got this error: ValueError: name for name_scope must be a string.
Here is my code test, a very simple one ..

```
model = ConvBlock(64)
y = tf.random.uniform((2,32,32,3))
print(model(y).shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tf.keras.keras.Sequential` takes list of layers, please try the following:

```
    self.conv = keras.Sequential([
        layers.Conv2D(filters=self.in_channels,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding="same",use_bias=False),    
        layers.Conv2D(filters=self.in_channels,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding="same", use_bias=False),
        ]
    )
```